# Including files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a website using codeigniter and I want to include the menu (options) file so that I could save all my time from independently pasting the code on every view I need. 
Or even if there is a common file for custom functions where I could place the code and call the function.
ANy help. My menu option is as follows.

```
 <h5>Admin Options</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="category/addCategory">Add a Category</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="category/updateCategory">Edit/Delete Category</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="link/addLink">Add a Link</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="link/updateLink">Edit/Delete Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>First</li>
                <li>First</li>
                <li>First</li>
                <li>First</li>

            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see by the answers there are a number of ways of doing this but honestly I don't see the point in a templating library as it's relatively easy to do on your own. I use templates for my entire site since it means I don't have to keep rewriting code. Below is how I do it.

Template.php This file loads the other parts of the template, it loads the header dependent on whether the user is logged in so I can add the user menus easily.

```
    <?php 
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header-admin', $title);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $title);
        }
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar',$sidebar_content);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$main_content);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
    ?>
```

Each of those pages is a static html file or as in the case of the main content and sidebar_content they're variables. So then from a controller I load my views like this (this is a basic page)

```
public function welcome()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'welcome';
    $this->load->model('someModel');
    $data['someArray'] = $this->someModel->someFunction();
    $data['title']='Welcome to example.com';
    $data['sidebar_content'] = 'sidebar/no_sidebar';
    $data['additionalHeadInfo'] ='';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);  
}
```

So what's happening above is the first line is the actual view getting loaded to main content this is a php page with nothing but the middle content of the site in it. Title fills in the title tags in the header. sidebar content loads the appropriate sidebar.php page (in this case it's an empty file). Additional head info is so I can load libraries or css pages specific to a single view. The final line brings it all together.

Edit - I added two lines for adding variable data. So you would do a call to your model like normal and return the data, but return it to an array inside the $data array. Then in your view you would access it like this (variables are obviously for example, you'd use whatever variables your model returns:

```
echo $someArray['userName'];
```

For the record normal PHP include statements work just fine in CI, it just makes a lot less sense than creating a template.

Comment: Thanks .. and I have one more question, What if i want to pass some data to that view so that I can display them in the view.??
say in our example I need to pass a $data array to the welcome view.. then display that array elements in that view. How do i do that?

Comment: I'll edit the answer, but it's just a matter of adding to that data variable we've already created.

Comment: Yes please do the editing.. I am new in codeigniter and for this very problem, I have been scratching my head for hours. And thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Just put your HTML in a view file "options_view.php" and anywhere you want to include this HTML snippet just load that view:

```
<?php $this->load->view('options_view') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [CodeIgniter's documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) and the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

There is something to be said for self-directed learning.

Answer (score 1):

Templating is going to be the answer for this. Since out of the box CI treats any view as essentially its own page, it is up to the user to either load other views progressively or to wrap all views except those loaded as strings into a common template.
Here is just one library to implement this:

http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

Personally I would not load all views progressively as Wolf states. Nothing wrong with this except that it can lead to maintainability problems. I would create as many templates as necessary - some may not need the options view, for example - and load the correct one with each method.